# Oracle user locks (dbms_lock): guaranteed order of requests granted?

Tags: oracle, locking

I was wondering if Oracle guarantees that the sequence of `dbms_lock.request` granted is the same as the sequence in which they were requested. 
In my tests it always was the case, but I couldn't find any official statement in the Oracle documentation.

So let's assume we have at least three sessions:

1. Session 1 requests the lock via `dbms_lock.request(1)` and is granted the lock immediately (as the lock is not yet held by any other session)
2. Session 2 requests the lock via `dbms_lock.request(1)` and has to wait
3. Session 3 requests the lock via `dbms_lock.request(1)` and also has to wait
4. Now Session 1 releases the lock via `dbms_lock.release(1)` (or trx end or session end)

Is it guaranteed that Session 2 will now receive the lock and Session 3 still has to wait until Session 2 releases? Or might Session 3 receive the lock before Session 2?

*Edit*: if the answer is "yes, guaranteed", please provide link to Oracle documentation, whitepaper, V$ view or the like.

*Edit 2*: Database version in question is 11g and up

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Yes!

There is a wait queue and the first requester is the first served.
Beware of deadlocks...

Comment: Do you know any official reference from Oracle like documentation or whitepaper, where this is documented?

Comment: -1 , that is not a useful answer without any references